# Page size for wireframing

Tags: grid, wireframe, size, page

I am using axure RP 30 day free trial and I have a startup idea. I need to make the website really quickly. But when I at the wireframe stage I encountered with a problem.Problem is, According to which page size (width) I need to design my website? My screen resolution is 1920x1080 but I don't know how to design for all screen sizes? But one more problem: Some people say use 960grid system but when I use 960 grid there is no screen resolution like 960x480 960x350 etc. Please help me I hope I explain well my problem thanks. Sorry for my bad english

Edit: I mean when I design the page for 960 grid Does that design fit bigger screen resolutions for example 1920x1080? Or Do I need to use 1200 grid system or 980 etc to fit the design bigger pages than 1024x780. When I design my page for 960 grid Will  my website be seen as 1024x768px on every screen? Which page size I need to use to wireframe my pages? My screen size is 1920x1080. I need to place my elements every corner of the page not just on the middle. So for this job Is it useful to design with 960grid? thanks

Comment: We can't really answer this without knowing what the idea is, who your audience is, what their needs are, what you business objectives are, etc. The only generic answer we can give you is to suggest you google "responsive web design".

Answer (score 0):

Different types of users use different resolutions. You will need to make *separate* wireframes for different resolutions. Just like if you were making a separate design for mobile.

The 960 grid is used because it fits on most screens, with the lowest common resolution at 1024. Most people then decide to centre the 960 grid so that if someone has a 1920 resolution screen, the 960 will appear in the centre.

If you want to fill up the page at every resolution, you will need to wireframe for 960, 1200, and whatever size comes bigger than that.

Comment: Is there a way to make design for all resolutions in one time? And Is there a way to design with 960 grid system for full screen resolution? I want full screen because 960 grid is middle on the screen its bad for me :(

Comment: I'm afraid not. 960 refers to the exact pixel width, so there's no way a 960 could "scale" to full size. 

I mean, it's a wireframe, so you could just design it as 960 and then when you make the real thing, or write requirements for the real thing, just tell them to scale it up.

Comment: @CaganKuyucu the 960 grid system is *not* a responsive grid system. If you want a responsive web site (works on all sizes) then you need a responsive grid system such as Bootstrap. As for how to wireframe for that, you really need to work in partnership with your developers to get the full picture.